# Git Diff and Grep a list of strings out

Tags: git, grep, cut, git-diff

If I get a list of files that have changed how can I pull a certain string out and print it?

`git diff --name-only origin/master`

Output:

```
server/packages/sharing/src/test1.js
client/packages/sharing/src/test2.js
client/packages/foo/src/test3.js
client/packages/foo/src/test4.js
client/packages/bar/src/test5.js
client/packages/bar/src/test6.js
client/packages/baz/src/test7.js
client/packages/baz/src/test8.js
```

I would like to get the third word in the path when examining the file list.

Trying to get:

```
sharing, foo, bar, baz
```

or

```
sharing
foo
bar
baz
```

I tried `git diff --name-only origin/master | grep -o '*/packages/*/src'` but I'm not sure how to capture the word. (using zsh on a Mac if it helps with narrowing down what's on my system)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can decompose your path with [`cut` command](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html) :

```
git diff --name-only origin/master | cut --delimiter / --fields 3
```

On Mac, try :

```
git diff --name-only origin/master | cut -d/ -f3
```

Comment: On mac you are bound to use the short argument name -d and -f.

Comment: `git diff --name-only origin/master | cut -d/ -f3 | uniq` helps remove dupes